# XamlParseException when using UserControl from class library dll

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-10, uwp

I have created a library which has a Popup UserControl [similar to the one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032750/how-to-center-a-popup-in-window-windows-store-apps).

When I create a fresh Universal Windows App and create the same UserControl inside an app and open the popup, it opens.

But if I create a Class Library and create the same UserControl inside it and try to use it (by opening the popup) inside an app, I get a XamlParseException.

It is as follows -

> Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
>       HResult=-2144665590
>       Message=XAML parsing failed.
>       Source=Windows
>       StackTrace:
>          at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation
>   componentResourceLocation)
>          at PopupTestLibrary.MyUserControl1.InitializeComponent()

I am not able to understand exactly why this is happening, since the code works fine when not called from an external class library.

Some Questions I found to be similar to mine, here on SO -

[XamlParseException when consuming a Page from a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895116/xamlparseexception-when-consuming-a-page-from-a-library)

[Cannot instantiate UserControl from another assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950097/cannot-instantiate-usercontrol-from-another-assembly-resource-cannot-be-found/32962744#32962744)

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Add a Resource Dictionary in your App and Add the Usercontrol Xaml content to it

as Xaml is Considered as a Content file not compiled into the code

Comment: Could you please elaborate??

Comment: When you Compile a dll with xaml file in it, it Converts in into xbf files those files must be copied as well to the bin directory of your app with relative path

Comment: Check your bin Folder when you compile your DLL you will get what I mean

Comment: You can Add your DLL as a Project reference in the project this will solve the problem, since it will copy all the bin Content folder automatically,

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. Could you also tell me whether this was the case with Windows Phone 8, as I have used UserControl before from class library in WP8 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this post is just as yours.. :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63f071be-a3c5-4f2d-ace2-73ca750e3252/rtm-usercontrol-class-library-and-assembly-name-with-

And, It's known issue:

[Dot in the project's name cause XAMLParseException](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa2d8d53-254c-4d4a-b39a-110fde0d6c80/dot-in-the-projects-name-cause-xamlparseexception?forum=winappswithcsharp)

I hope that this will help you in your issue..

Comment: The name of my library is "PopupTestLibrary". It contains no dot ".". And that bug was for Visual Studio 2012 AFAIK.