# Xamarin Forms Project with netstandard: can't build UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

currently I'm working on a Xamarin app, which uses the .Net-Standard code sharing strategy.
While I ca build and run the succesfully on android, i have some problems with the UWP project.

When I try to build the project I'm receiving this error messages:

> Could not copy the file "obj\x86\Debug\myapp.UWP.xr.xml" because it
> was not found.
>
> Could not copy the file "obj\x86\Debug\MainPage.xbf" because it was
> not found.
>
> Could not copy the file "obj\x86\Debug\App.xbf" because
> it was not found.
>
> Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot
> resolve assembly: myapp.Basic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null.'

While I was looking for these error messages I found this thread on stackoverflow:

[Missing xaml.xr of a class library file in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847919/missing-xaml-xr-of-a-class-library-file-in-uwp)

The thread suggestes to enable the "Generate library layout" in projects that contains XAML-code, which looked very promising, because the myapp.Basic Project contains some XAML-code. Unluckily this option is totaly missing in .Net-standard projects.

Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried clean your solution and redeploy it before building?

Comment: Yes of course, this was was first thing I have tried :)

Comment: And this option only applies to `ClassLibrary`.

Comment: You could try delete `bin` `obj` folder in UWP project manually.

Comment: make sure the MinTarget Build for UWP is set to at least Build 16299

Comment: Finally we solved the problem by deleting and adding again all references

Answer (score 5):

In your UWP Project manually add reference to any additional .Net Standard Class library project

in your case to myapp.Basic

Comment: That did the trick for me when adding a UWP project to an existing Xamarin.Forms project. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Bu sure that you add all .Net Standard Class libraries references in your solution to UWP project. For Android and IOS projects adding the main shared code project's reference is enough; but for UWP if you have an extra class library project that your shared code project use you have to add this project too as a reference to UWP project.